# Overloading assignment operator in a class template

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef NUMBER_HPP
#define NUMBER_HPP

template <class T>
class Number
{
public:
Number( T value ) : m_value( value )
{
}

T value() const
{
 return m_value;
}

void setValue( T value )
{
 m_value = value;
}

Number<T>& operator=( T value )
{
 m_value = value;
}

//  template <class T2>
//  Number<T2>& operator=( const Number<T>& number )
//  {
//    m_value = number.value();

//    return *this;
//  }

private:
 T m_value;
};

typedef Number<int> Integer;
typedef Number<char*> Float;

#endif // NUMBER_HPP
```

This template class is initialized with two data types seperatly. one is int type and other is char pointer type.

```
   typedef Number<int> Integer1,Integer2;
   typedef Number<char*> Char1,Char2;
   Integer2.setValue(2) ;
   Char2.setValue("ABC");
   Integer1 = Interger2;//Case 1
   Char1 = Char2; // Case 2
```

In case 1:
Deep copy is not required.

In case 2: 
Deep copy is must as we are copying the  pointers.

But as both of the classes uses same base copy of assignment operator. how can we achieve this?

Please suggest a solution which does not include C++ 11.

Comment: So, you can do template specialization for that.

Comment: it is not only about char*. it may have int* , float* as well as custom data types.

Comment: restrict yourself to useing something with value semantics as temp param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just want to overload your `operator=`'s:

```
template <class T2>
Number<T>& operator=( const Number<T2*>& number )
{
    // Deep Copy
}

template <class T2>
Number<T>& operator=( const Number<T2>& number )
{
    // Shallow Copy
}
```

In probably all other cases you want `std::enable_if` to statically decide which copy stategy shall be used depending on the type (most likely whether it is a pointer type, therefore e.g. `std::is_pointer<T2>::value`). This can then very easily simplified by `if constexpr` (C++17):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T2>
Number<T>& operator=( const Number<T2>& number )
{
    if constexpr( std::is_pointer_v<T2> ){
        // Deep Copy
    }
    else{
        // Shallow Copy
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a term like std::is_pointer<>  . One more thing, why do we need to use constexpr?

Comment: You don't have to, but that simplifies things sometimes. E.g. you can eliminate std::enable_if's with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.  You're assigning a `T2` to a `T`.  That means we need to take a `Number<T2>`, cast the value to `T`, then assign to `this` and `return *this`.

```
template <class T2 >
Number<T>& operator=( const Number<T2>& number )
{
  m_value = T( number.value() );

  return *this;
}
```

Comment: No, i am not assigning the value of T1 into T2. My que was , a templete class can be initialized with two type of datatypes. one is simple that is int other is pointer such as char* or int*(both of these types will have different classes for compilation). In case it is initialized with char* , we need to do deep copy but if it is done by int, deep copy is not required. How do we perform this ?