# Overloading assignment operator in a class template when it is initialized with both int and char*

Tags: c++, c++03

```
#ifndef NUMBER_HPP
#define NUMBER_HPP

template <class T>
class Number
{
public:
Number( T value ) : m_value( value )
{
}

T value() const
{
 return m_value;
}

void setValue( T value )
{
 m_value = value;
}

Number<T>& operator=( T value )
{
 m_value = value;
}

//  template <class T2>
//  Number<T2>& operator=( const Number<T>& number )
//  {
//    m_value = number.value();

//    return *this;
//  }

private:
 T m_value;
};

typedef Number<int> Integer;
typedef Number<char*> Float;

#endif // NUMBER_HPP
```

This template class is initialized with two data types seperatly. one is int type and other is char pointer type.

```
typedef Number<int> Integer1,Integer2;
typedef Number<char*> Char1,Char2;
Integer2.setValue(2) ;
Char2.setValue("ABC");
Integer1 = Interger2;//Case 1
Char1 = Char2; // Case 2
```

In case 1: Deep copy is not required.

In case 2: Deep copy is must as we are copying the pointers.

But as both of the classes uses same base copy of assignment operator. how can we achieve this?

Please suggest a solution which does not include C++ 11.

Comment: `Number<char*>` is terrible code to maintain.

Comment: [Haven't we seen this before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176460/overloading-assignment-operator-in-a-class-template)

Comment: Your class doesn't own the `char*`, so deep copy doesn't make sense here. If you want the class to own the `char*` you will also have to change the constructors and destructor. But it's much better to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.